# cross library dependency with CDI

Tags: java, jpa, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, cdi

I've done a 'lot' of googling for this over the past 48 hour and I am still coming up blank, so I'm hoping that a question here might help.

I'm developing a switchyard service (actually I'll be developing a whole suite of them hence this approach) and I want to have the JPA based dao code and entities off in a separate jar, as well as another jar for other DTO/Interface stuff.

both of these other jars contain CDI beans, and beans.xmls, and the DAO jar contains a valid persistence.xml which is connecting to a JDNI datasource in my JBoss app server.

My initial thought was to have both the jars loaded as EE modules, as this seemed like a sensible thing, which gave me problems around CDI injection in that my switchyard app couldn't see the beans, but I realised that was just the module.xml not having configured the appropriate dependencies to allow weld to load the CDI beans.

After that however I couldn't get the persistence unit to load into the DAO.  the entity manager kept coming up null, whether I had persistence.xml in the module, or in the switchyard app.  (and I did have javax.persistence in the module.xml)

Some reading up on modules leads me to believe that JPA won't work over this approach (if someone can point me to how to make it work, that will answer this question!)

So I switched to trying to bundle my switchyard service jar in an EAR with the other two jars.

My ear structure is:

```
+-
  sw-service.jar
  dao.jar
  dto.jar
  +-META-INF
    application.xml
```

and my application.xml contains

```
<application>
    <module>
        <java>sw-service.jar</java>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>dao.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>dto.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

When I try to deploy I get the following errors:

```
10:00:51,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" (runtime-name: "sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear") 10:00:51,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "sy-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar") 10:00:51,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar") 10:00:51,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "dto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar") 10:00:51,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for my_pu 10:00:51,974 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear 10:00:51,984 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment sy-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 10:00:51,993 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 10:00:51,985 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment dto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 10:00:52,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-6) JNDI bindings for session bean named ActivitiesDAO in deployment unit subdeployment "dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ActivitiesDAO!org.test.rich.dao.ActivitiesDAO
        java:app/dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ActivitiesDAO!org.test.rich.dao.ActivitiesDAO
        java:module/ActivitiesDAO!org.test.rich.dao.ActivitiesDAO
        java:global/sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ActivitiesDAO
        java:app/dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ActivitiesDAO
        java:module/ActivitiesDAO   10:00:52,076 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear 10:00:52,102 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear 10:00:52,103 INFO  [org.switchyard] (MSC service thread 1-1) Deploying SwitchYard application 'sy-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' 10:00:52,233 INFO  [org.switchyard] (MSC service thread 1-6) Deploying SwitchYard application 'dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' 10:00:52,239 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"."dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: JBAS 018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardDeploymentProcessor.deploy(SwitchYardDeploymentProcessor.java:119)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
        ... 5 more   10:00:52,485 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: {
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".INSTALL"
=> "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" of deployment \"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".deploymentCompleteService]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#my_pu\"]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".ActivitiesDAO.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".ActivitiesDAO]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".ActivitiesDAO.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".ActivitiesDAO]"
    ] } 10:00:52,496 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear 10:00:52,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: dto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) in 74ms 10:00:52,562 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: dao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) in 76ms 10:00:52,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: sy-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) in 75ms 10:00:52,578 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear (runtime-name: sy-service-ear-deployment-assembly-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear) in 92ms
```

Can anyone either let me know how I can get the persistence unit to go across between switchyard services and JBoss modules, or what I'm missing with my EAR file as I'm completely at a loss on this one?